# window.btoa not working for PNG and JPEG files

Tags: javascript, image, encoding, base64

I convert file that are uploaded on the GUI and decoded it on the server which is a node.js server. Following code works fine for PDF files etc. but does not work for Image files ( PNG and JPEG). Following is the code :-

```
var fileName = form.findField("attachment").fileInputEl.dom.files[0];
                            var fileReader = new FileReader();
                            fileReader.onload = function (olEvent) {
                                var payload = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(olEvent.target.result)));
                                contactObj['file_content'] = payload;
                                contactObj['file_name'] = fileName.name;
                                contactObj['file_type'] = fileName.type;
                                contactObj['file_size'] = fileName.size;
                                contactObj['fileAttached'] = fileAttached;
                                me.postContactUs(contactObj);
                                };
                            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(fileName);
                            }
```

on the node server using an npm (base-64) to decode this. Any ideas??

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: After decoding the 'file_content' I attach that content to an email. When the content happens to be an image( jpeg or png), the image is not formed and the attachment cannot be opened. Following is the segment of my server code var binary_content = base64.decode( rb.file_content )